# Mvc controller to view from sql Ienumerable problem

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get all the info (column, rows) from a table in SQL and send it as a model to the view.

I also want it to be Distinct.

My controller:

```
        MVCEntities me = new MVCEntities();
        List<CarsCategory> arr = me.CarsCategories.ToList();
        return View(arr);
```

My view model:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarsCategory>
```

In the view I'm trying to loop through a certain column like this:

```
    <select id="SelectManufacturer">

        @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
            <option value="@i.Manufacturer">@i.Manufacturer</option>
        }
    </select>
```

How do I make it Distinct? When I try to add Distinct it gives me `system.linq.enumerable+<DistinctIterator> ..`

Comment: please share the exact error details and where did you try distinct? have you tried me.CarsCategories.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @BalajiM It's not an error. When I loop through i.manufacturer without the distinct (Like the example above) it gives me the same name a few times, and when I add distinct to i.manufacturer like this (i.manufacturer.distinct()) it gives me "system.linq.enumerable+<distinctIterator>" instead of the real names

Comment: Use distinct at controller not view List<CarsCategory> arr = me.CarsCategories.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: If you just need distinct Names [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28112531/2030565) and filter this in your controller before returning to the view.

Comment: @BalajiM Still not working. already tried that. still gives the same name over and over

Comment: me.CarsCategories.Select(s=>s.Manufacturer).Distinct().ToList() or use groupby

Comment: @Jasen no it's not good, it forces me to choose a column. I want the whole table

Comment: @BalajiM I need the model to contain the whole table. when I use lambda expression it forces me to choose a column

Comment: choose the column whatever you want

Comment: @BalajiM Man, I'm working in my view with more than just one Select tag! I have a few more Select tags that I want to create and they need to be based on another columns from the table, I hope you understand me

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a good approach to process data inside the view, your solution might look like this:

```
<select id="SelectManufacturer">
    @{
        var manufacturers = Model.Select(x => x.Manufacturer).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var i in manufacturers)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller should be responsible to supply the View with the data, the view should not be polutted with a bunch of logic to try to aggregate this data unless you want unmaintainable code. The best approach is to extend your view model to have multiple properties.

#### Models

```
public class CategoryModel{
    public List<CarsCategory> CarCategories {get;set;}
    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturers {get;set;}
}

public class Manufacturer{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

#### Controller code

```
// you need to ensure that if you are using EF the context is disposed after you are done using it!
using(MVCEntities me = new MVCEntities()) {
  var model = new CategoryModel();
  model.CarCategories = me.CarsCategories.ToList();
  // you need to supply the correct Id and Name locations in your model as you did not share this
  model.Manufacturers = model.CarCategories.Select(x => new Manufacturer(){Id = x.prop.id, Name = x.prop.name}).Distinct();
  return View(model);
}
```

#### Razor View

```
@model CategoryModel

<select id="SelectManufacturer">

    @foreach (var i in Model.Manufacturers)
    {
        <option value="@i.Id">@i.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```